# Printing Dates within a Text File

Tags: linux, bash

I'm attempting to write a script that prints out the name of the directory if its newest file is older than 3 days. The caveat is that this is being done in a text file, who's contents include the output of the command `cat directoryName > file.txt`.
Example output of file.txt excluding directories 2 and 3:

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Aug  3 00:00 Directory1
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Aug 15 00:00 Directory2
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Aug 15 00:00 Directory3

/root/Downloads/syslog/Directory1:
total 12
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 18 Aug 20 00:00 file1
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  9 Jun 23 00:00 file2
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  9 Dec  8  2022 file3
```

Pulling the newest files and filtering them using `-mtime` is simple from the terminal, but how can I do this in a text file?

Comment: You will have to read the contents, extract the date from every line, and compare that date to today's date.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here? Is this something that could be solved by watching a specific set of directories for new files. e.g. using incrontab to watch specific folders for new files written?

Answer (score 0):

please, check if it can help you:

```
#!/bin/bash
######################################################################
# Script Configuration
######################################################################
readonly INPUT_FILENAME=file.txt
readonly NUMBER_OF_DAYS=3

######################################################################
# Global variables
######################################################################
g_current_directory=""
g_current_time_in_seconds=$(date "+%s")
g_number_of_days_in_seconds=$(( ${NUMBER_OF_DAYS} * 24 * 60 * 60 ))

g_max_age_in_seconds=$(( ${g_current_time_in_seconds} - ${g_number_of_days_in_seconds} ))

######################################################################
# Checks the record type
# Arguments:
#  l_record - A single record from the file to be evaluated
# Returns:
#  0 - The record is a directory information record
#  1 - The record is a directory name
#  2 - The record is a file information record
#  3 - Error detecting the record type
######################################################################
function check_record_type() {
  local l_record="$1"

  local l_record_type=3

  if [[ "${l_record}" =~ ^d.........\ .* ]]; then
    l_record_type=0
  elif [[ "${l_record}" =~ ^/.*: ]]; then
    l_record_type=1
  elif [[ "${l_record}" =~ ^-.........\ .* ]]; then
    l_record_type=2
  fi

  return ${l_record_type}
}

##### Start processing ###############################################

# Read the file line by line (record by record)
while read record ; do
  # Gets the current record type
  check_record_type "${record}"
  record_type=$?

  # We just evaluate the types 1 (directory name) and 2 (file information record)
  case ${record_type} in
    1) if [[ ! -z "${g_current_directory}" ]] &&
          [[ ${recent_file_exists_in_dir} == false ]]; then
         echo "${g_current_directory}"
       fi
       g_current_directory=$( echo "${record}" | tr -d ':' )
       recent_file_exists_in_dir=false
       ;;

    2) filename=$( echo "${record}" | awk '{print $9}' )
       file_date=$( echo "${record}" | awk '{print $6 " " $7 " " $8}' )
       file_date_in_seconds=$( date -d"${file_date}" +"%s" )

       # Check if the file is between the boundaries of
       # n days ago and the current time. The comparison is evaluated
       # in seconds.
       if [[ ${file_date_in_seconds} -gt ${g_max_age_in_seconds} ]] &&
          [[ ${file_date_in_seconds} -lt ${g_current_time_in_seconds} ]]; then             
         # Yes, we have recent files,
         # Set the flag to exclude this directory from the listing
         recent_file_exists_in_dir=true
       fi
       ;;

    *) # Skip records that are different from types 1 and 2.
  esac

done < ${INPUT_FILENAME}

if [[ ! -z "${g_current_directory}" ]] &&
   [[ ${recent_file_exists_in_dir} == false ]]; then
    echo "${g_current_directory}"
fi
```